# Where can I see my files for Azure pipelines / container registry?

Tags: azure, docker

I have the following Azure setup for a Docker app:

- Azure Devops Pipeline pulls from GH
- Pipelines YAML is pointing to my Azure Container Registry and a specific image (repo) within it
- Pipelines builds Docker container

What I can't work out is **how or where to see which actual files were pulled from GH**.

I want to see this because my container is exiting after complaining that a file is missing, which shouldn't be the case as it's in the branch that the Pipeline is pulling from.

What I've tried:

- Kudu, via `<myapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net` > Browse directory > Site root - this shows nothing except a file called `hostingstart.html`
- FTP - same deal as above
- Interrogate container - not an option because the container quits on the error, taking the virtual filesystem with it
- Pipeline - interrogating the run steps (specific files fetched from GH aren't mentioned)

How can I view which files came up the pipeline?